# Using Custom Unary Predicates With boost::mpl::find_if in C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I have a number of different class types each with the member function `GetParameterString()` which returns a string specific to the class. I'd like to be able to store these class types in a `boost::mpl::list` and compare `GetParameterString` to a test string that I receive from another source. So if I have 3 *class types*, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
const std::string input_string = "Random String";

using ClassTypes = boost::mpl::list<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>;
auto it = boost::mpl::find_if<ClassTypes>( [&input_string](auto next_class){
          return input_string.compare(next_class.GetParameterString() )
});
it->CallSomeOtherCommonClassMethod();
```

There are two problems here. First the return value is an `int` and not a `bool`. But more importantly, how I've set up the call to `boost::mpl::find_if` seems incorrect even if I return a `bool`.

One of my requirements here is to stick to boost::mpl. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`boost::mpl` library is mostly compile-time-only, and it operates purely on types rather than values (`boost::mpl::for_each` is an exception). The result of its `find_if` is one of the classes, not a value of any type. "lambda" passed in it is not the usual C++ lambda either.

You *may* be able to achieve what you want if `getParameterString()` is `static constexpr` member function. You would need to figure out how to create the right type `Predicate`. Once you have that, your code should look like:

```
using ClassTypes = boost::mpl::list<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>;
using iter = boost::mpl::find_if<ClassTypes, Predicate>::type;
boost::mpl::deref<iter>::type::CallSomeOtherCommonClassMethod();
```

Comment: In my example, ClassA, ClassB and ClassC are all class types. I've been able to get `boost::mpl::for_each` to work for another problem, so I don't think my confusion is with the operating on types.

Is my error here that I'm mixing compile-time-only types with runtime strings in `boost::mpl::find_if`? That is, does my predicate have to compile-time-only?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm leaning towards believing that my use of `boost::mpl::find_if` is incorrect as opposed to not using `boost::mpl` as a complie-time-only library used on types. For reference, I use `boost::mpl::for_each` in in the following, without any issue and get exactly what I want:

```
boost::mpl::for_each<ClassTypes>([&input_string](auto next_class) {
     if (next_class.GetParameterString() == input_string) {
               // DO SOMETHING
     }});
```

Comment: Please, remove this answer and make it a part of your question instead.